# How to use UIButton instead of Barbutton in Master-Detail template

Tags: ios, xcode, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail, popover

I want to use Custom UIButton instead of BarButton in Master-Detail Application template.

Please advice to me.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Succeed in solving a problem !!!!

myCode is :

```
-(IBAction)click_MenuButton:(id)sender
{

    [self.masterPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:[sender frame] inView:self.view  permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: What's the view controller in masterPopoverController?

Answer (score 1):

You can use any UIView in a UIBarButtonItem by using initWithCustomView:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBarButtonItem/initWithCustomView:

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simply create a UIToolBar in the xib, and drag a UIButton onto it.
A UIBarButtonItem with an embedded UIButton will be created automatically.